# React-native layout with center element and bottom container that should grow with children

Tags: react-native, layout, flexbox

I have a layout that keeps occurring in my codebase, that I'm not able to style properly with react-native flex only.

I want to have a top and bottom container which initially should both take half the screen space. The bottom container should grow with it's children and the top container should shrink if need be.

I've created a snack with the code here, where the layout **behaves as it should**, but it's using a workaround via **onLayout**: https://snack.expo.io/@domir/center-problem

[image: example]

The same problem is easily solved in web via `flex: 1` on both containers. In react-native if I have `flexGrow: 1` on both of them, they only divide leftover whitespace.

E.g. Currently for a display height 1000 a top container will get 400 while bottom container will get 400 + 200 when a 200 child is placed there when using `flexGrow: 1`. What I want is both to get 500 until the bottom container has 3 children with 200 each. Then I want the top container to get 400 and the bottom to have 600.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's a way to solve this JUST with flex (probably not) - and I'm not sure what your requirements are, but here's a way to solve that without using `onLayout` but instead just use `maxHeight` percentages:

https://snack.expo.io/@sudoplz/center_problem_maybe_solved

All I actually did was I used the existing counter value you had in that snack, to modify the input of `maxHeight`

The top parent is now styled like that:

```js
maxHeight: `${Math.min(50, ITEM_HEIGHT - counter * ITEM_HEIGHT_PERCENTAGE)}%`
```

which means that until the bottom parent is full, it's max value will be `50%`, as soon as it's full, the maxHeight becomes less and less gradually (depending on he number of children on the bottom view)

In my snack I also got rid of some unnecessary views you had, not sure why they were there.

Here's how that looks like now:

[image: snack preview]

Would that work for you?

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion but I've checked this on a real device and it does not work as expected, but see below.

Comment: From my experience, on Android there may be issues with percentages values, but you can still use screen percentage values like so: maxHeight: itemPercentage/totalScreenHeight , that&#39;s what we do in production and it works great!

Comment: I see, that's good to know. This would work great if I knew the height of the lower part in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see below, the maxHeight solution does not work quite well on a real device. Some of the lower boxes are cropped off or overflow the screen.

Although the solution does not have to be with flex only, I do have a flexible container at the bottom. It contains text and a varying amount of error messages. The yellow space would contain whitespace and the green container would contain some text input. On large screens, this is not a problem, but for small devices, the error messages can take up quite a bit of space and I'm not able to calculate the size of the lower parts in advance.

[image]